# Convert $u_{xx}+yu_{yy}=0$ into a first order PDE system.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative

Let's say that we have the second-order PDE which has hyperbolic form

\begin{align}u_{xx}+yu_{yy}=0 \label{1}\tag1
\end{align}

We know $a=1, \ b=0,\ c=y$

Thus, the discriminant is:
$$d=b^2-ac=-y$$

So the equation is hyperbolic form when $y<0$.

It is clear that

\begin{align}u_{xx}+yu_{yy}&=0 \Leftrightarrow \\  \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}^2}&=-y \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{y}^2}
\end{align}

The question is how to formulate the \eqref{1} as a first order PDE system:
$$\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{x}}+A \frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{y}}=0$$
where $Q$ vector in $\mathbb{R}$ and A is matrix $2 \times 2$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have $u_{xx} + f(y)u_{yy} = 0$. Then
\begin{align}
u_x &= -f(y) v_y, \\
v_x &= u_y
\end{align}
is a simple representation of it as a first-order system. In your case $f(y) = y$.

Comment: I made the following consideration Let c=-y
It is clearly that 

\begin{align}u_{xx}+yu_{yy}&=0\\ \Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial^2{x}}-
c \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial^2{y}}&=0\\ \Leftrightarrow \bigg(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}\bigg)^2-
\bigg(\sqrt{c} \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}\bigg)^2&=0\\ \bigg( \frac{\partial u }{\partial x} - \sqrt{c} \frac{\partial u }{\partial y} \bigg)
\bigg( \frac{\partial u }{\partial x} + \sqrt{c} \frac{\partial u }{\partial y} \bigg)&=0
\end{align}
So $$u_{x} + \sqrt{c} u_{y} = 0$$
$$u_{x} - \sqrt{c} u_{y} = 0$$. Is it right?

Comment: I do not want just the solution, I want to understand the way we solve it.

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos The proposed answer is correct. However, your proposition in the above comments does not look right: $u_{xx} \not \equiv (u_x)^2$.

Comment: @EditPiAf ok, I got it! Thank you!